# ¿Cómo hacer en latex que la figura sea renderizada luego de ser referenciada?

Tags: latex

Ahora mismo estoy creando mi figura de esta manera:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Ejemplo de curvas ROC}
  \label{fig:eg-roc}
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{graficos/eg_roc.png}
\end{figure}
```

Y la estoy referenciando con este comando:

```
\ref{fig:eg-roc}
```

Y a pesar de que estoy poniendo la referencia antes del bloque de la figura, en el pdf generado la figura aparece antes de la referencia.

Answer (score 1):

El paquete `flafter` (que forma parte de latex y por tanto viene preinstalado) te arregla el problema:

```tex
\usepackage{flafter}
```

Este paquete se asegura de que la figura no sale nunca antes del punto donde la insertes en el fuente.

Ten en cuenta no obstante que como norma general es mejor dejar que LaTeX ponga la figura donde considere conveniente (en función de qué más texto aparece en la página, qué espacio hay disponible, si hay otras figuras, etc.)

Si el documento es complicado, largo, con muchas figuras, tratar de "forzar" su posición acaba siendo un trabajo de relojería, pues cada vez que "mueves" una figura tienes que revisar y quizás recomponer todo.